# Pagination using Structure and Playa entries

Tags: playa, structure, url, pagination, related-entries

Currently on a site using Structure. I've run into a brainteaser I hope someone maybe able to help out with.

The site itself makes use of Structures child pages. In my case these child pages relate to Recipes. ie. the parent page would be Recipes with a child of Main Courses, which would then have child pages of Fish courses, Pasta courses etc. In the publish form of these child pages I have a Playa field, which link documents/recipes from my documents channel.

Thats all fine, but some child pages have a lot of related documents assigned to them, so I want to integrate pagination if possible to avoid long scrolling pages.

This is the bare bones of my markup

```
{exp:channel:entries status="not closed" dynamic="on"}


    {if related_docs}<!--My Playa field-->

    {exp:playa:children 
        channel="documents" 
        disable="categories|category_fields|member_data" 
        orderby="title" 
        sort="asc" 
        limit="5" 
        var_prefix="pages" 
        paginate_base="/{segment_1}/{segment_2}/{segment_3}" 
        paginate="bottom"}


    <h5>{pages:title}</h5>

    <!--Pagination start-->

{pages:paginate}
{pagination_links}
<ul>
  {first_page}
    <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-first">First Page</a></li>
  {/first_page}

  {previous_page}
    <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous">Previous Page</a></li>
  {/previous_page}

  {page}
    <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} {if current_page}active{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
  {/page}

  {next_page}
    <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next">Next Page</a></li>
  {/next_page}

  {last_page}
    <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-last">Last Page</a></li>
  {/last_page}
</ul>
{/pagination_links}
{/pages:paginate}


    {/exp:playa:children}

    {if:else}

    <p style="padding:15px;">Currently no resources for this area</p>

    {/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I have read about using pagination within a Playa field, hence the inclusion of `var_prefix`. But the pagination just doesn't seem to be working.

Right now if I navigate to my Structure child page with the related entries displayed, the URL is `domain.com/recipes/main-courses/meat-dishes/`.

Using the default `pagination_url`, this takes me to `domain.com/recipes/main-courses/meat-dishes/P5`  . Which implies the pagination URL's are being correctly applied. But when I click on the next page I am merely taken to the homepage, with the `P5` paginated url.

Am I missing something glaringly obvious with this one. Has anyone had any success with this or can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Is meat-dishes an actual Structure page with a listing attached? That's the only way Structure can know to properly paginate.

Comment: No, meat-dishes is a just a standard structure page with a related documents channel field. The documents assigned to it come from this, not from a listing. Can pagination not work this way?